# flutter pub get not working after updating flutter 2.5

Tags: flutter

Hy hope so all are good and fine! i am new to flutter and after updating flutter version to 2.5 i am facing this type of errors as in images below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sqVw.p)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9PvQ.png)

Error is:
flutter pub get
Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org".
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...
Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org".
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_application_1...

Comment: Is your Internet good? (Check your firewall settings).

Comment: yes! that's the real problem but when i am using older version of flutter it is not required to internet connectivity while creating new flutter project but when i upgrade flutter software development kit to 2.5 then i am facing this error while creating flutter new project it seems that this is dependencies error but when i connect to internet flutter project is successfully created but i am not able to understand why i am required to connect to internet

Comment: Could you please verify if you have any antivirus firewall is blocking pub, gradlew, google, android studio?

Comment: if you use Kaspersky internet security that has the highest probability.

Comment: please add "dart" also to the firewall checking list.

Answer (score -1):

Just accept android licenses to the run below command on terminal, I also face this problem when I upgrading my flutter and I have solve my issue on below command, hope its help to you

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

And accept the terms on the terminal

Comment: thanks! but i have already accepted the android licenses as you can see here C:\Users\swiss>flutter doctor --android-licenses
All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates...

Comment: NOT worked for me. I have run your suggested command. Thanks.

Comment: What was exactly problem