# Flutter v2.5.0 Android Splash Screen

Tags: android, flutter, dart, splash-screen

I had implemented a native splash screen in my current project and everything was working correctly since I upgraded to v2.5.0 and I am starting to get this deprecation warning on my console:

> A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.

I have checked out the given link (which is not that clear btw) and tells me to remove the `o.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable` API as flutter now automatically displays the splash.

But after running my app without the code no splash screen appears moreover it takes a while to start the app - probably initializing the app without the splash or something.

Am I doing this right or is it an issue with the framework itself?

Comment: Try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69140837/13997210) hope it's helpful to you

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil no it didn't :(

Comment: I am having the exact same problem, after removing the recommended lines in "AndroidManifest.xml" my custom splash screen is no longer displayed. What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69232039/14212524

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil NOT worked for me. I have run your suggested command. Thanks.

Comment: @MuhammadIdrees Did you find the solution?

Comment: No I still haven't found a solution that works for me :(

Comment: Didi you find any solution yet? None of the answers seem to understand your question : (

Answer (score 66):

It is caused by having the following code in your AndroidManifest.xml, which was included by default in previous versions of Flutter:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
    android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
/>
```

The solution is to remove the above code.

[Source](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash)

Comment: Does not work correctly. After removing the recommended lines in "AndroidManifest.xml" my custom splash screen is no longer displayed. What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: The full, official splash screen migration guide is [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/android/splash-screen-migration).  The relevant step referenced in this answer is step 3; "Delete the meta-data element..."

Answer (score 12):

Follow this youtube tutorial on how to correctly Create Splash Screen in Flutter App the Right Way in 2021. Ensure to create the launch_background.xml file in both drawable and drawable-v21 folders inside the android/app/src/main/res folder.

[Create Splash Screen in Flutter App the Right Way in 2021](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVpFNfnuOZM)

If you are using Flutter 2.5, remove the following line in your AndroidManifest.xml file since Flutter 2.5 has no need for it anymore as mentioned here --> [android splash migration](https://flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration)

```
<meta-data
 android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
 android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"/>
```

Answer (score 11):

Remove the below lines from your AndroidManifest.xml file. In newer versions it's no longer used

```js
<meta-data
     android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
     android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            
<meta-data
      android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
      android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution that worked in my case.

You have a "drawable" and "drawable-v21" folders on the path "android/app/src/main/res/" and you must open the "launch_background.xml" in "drawable-v21" folder, paste and a little bit refactor my code to provide your image or/and color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/your_color" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/your_image" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

P.S. The image should be in "drawable" folder, not "drawable-v21". You can try, but in my case that didnt work and throw the error.

P.S.2 I didn't change the "AndroidManifest.xml", "styles.xml" and other files.