# Flutter (2.5) - A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

I am new to flutter and recently tried to develop a test app for learning sake with latest version Flutter 2.5. By looking at some tutorial online, I have added `flutter_native_splash: ^1.2.3` package for splash screen. And works fine.

However, when I launch app for the first time, it shows following debug message

> W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(18569): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.

After visiting the above link, I am not able to understand much what is supposed to be done.

Code in pubspec.yaml

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#FFFFFF"
  color_dark: "#000000"
  image: assets/images/splash_720.png
  android: true
  ios: true
  android12: true
```

Also, compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion is set to 31 in build.gradle

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### To avoid that warning you just need to remove that API usage from your project.

### Remove these lines of code from the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

[image: Remove these lines of code]

> Previously, Android Flutter apps would either set `io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable` in their application manifest, or implement `provideSplashScreen` within their Flutter Activity. This would be shown momentarily in between the time after the Android launch screen is shown and when Flutter has drawn the first frame. This is no longer needed and is deprecated – Flutter now automatically keeps the Android launch screen displayed until Flutter has drawn the first frame. Developers should instead remove the usage of these APIs. - [source](http://flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration)

---

### UPDATE (FLUTTER 2.8.0)

As per the flutter 2.8.0 update, The newly created project doesn't have this warning.

They removed unused API from `Androidmanifest.yml` but still have belove mentioned code.

[image: They still have these lines of code]

Answer (score 4):

Remove the below lines from the android manifest file. It's no longer used

```js
 <meta-data
       android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
       android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"/>
           
 <meta-data
       android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
       android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"/>
```