# Splash screen is woking on debug apk and is showing blank page on Release apk in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, splash-screen

I'm working on a flutter mobile application, while testing the mobile application on the Debug APK it shows the Splash screen perfectly when I created a Release APK the splash screen was not working perfectly. Here I'm showing the codes of the Splash screen.

```
import 'package:calculator_vault/globals.dart' as globals;
import 'package:calculator_vault/views/category.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';

class LoadingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoadingPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoadingPageState createState() => _LoadingPageState();
}

class _LoadingPageState extends State<LoadingPage> {
  double value = 0;
  void downloadData() {
    new Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 50), (Timer timer) {
      if (globals.loadNow) {
        print('loading now');
        setState(() {
          if (value >= 1) {
            timer.cancel();

            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage()));
          } else {
            value = value + 0.015;

        
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    downloadData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
        child: Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
          children: [
            Positioned(
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 22,
                child: Container(
                    height: 70,
                    width: 70,
                    child: Lottie.asset('assets/animations/loader.json'))
                    ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              child: Text(
                'Version 2.7.3',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Positioned(
                      child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              border: Border.all(
                                  width: 1.0, color: Color(0xffE8E3E3))),
                          width: 90,
                          height: 90,
                          child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                              child: Image.asset(
                                  'assets/app_icons/app_icon_0.png'))),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 25,
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.9,
                      child: Text(
                        'Calculator Lock',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've no clue why is it happening, please let me know.

"HERE IS MY FLUTTER LOGS"

```
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 9172): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
I/flutter ( 9172): Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:44415/EJIiR5NchMU=/
I/flutter ( 9172): Ad IDS: /21952429235,22639636745/TTS_CALCULATORLOCKCALCULATOR_BANNER_AD /21952429235,22639636745/TTS_CALCULATORLOCKCALCULATOR_BANNER_AD /21952429235,22639636745/TTS_CALCULATORLOCKCALCULATOR_BANNER_AD ca-app-pub-5709217593772841/6100863205 ca-app-pub-5709217593772841/6100863205 /21952429235,22639636745/TTS_CALCULATORLOCKCALCULATOR_NATIVE_AD /21952429235,22639636745/TTS_CALCULATORLOCKCALCULATOR_NATIVE_AD /21952429235,22639636745/TTS_CALCULATORLOCKCALCULATOR_NATIVE_AD /21952429235,22639636745/TTS_CALCULATORLOCKCALCULATOR_NATIVE_AD
I/flutter ( 9172): AppOpenAd failed to load: LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: null, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: []))
I/flutter ( 9172): Result : InterstitialAdResult.ERROR {error_message: No fill. We are not able to serve ads to this person. Please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/faq#a12. If you are integrating Audience Network for the first time, you can use test ads https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing., error_code: 1001, invalidated: true, placement_id: 3752483214787237_3752491351453090}
I/flutter ( 9172): 1 /storage/emulated/0/.CalculatorVault/hideFiles
I/flutter ( 9172): true
I/flutter ( 9172): ad is loaded
I/flutter ( 9172): Title Text :
```

Comment: run $ flutter logs in release and see what the error is and post it here

Comment: Okay, I've added that in the question

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code from your AndroidManifest.xml and it should work

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
    android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
/>
```

Ref: [StackOverflow answer on deprecated Splash Api](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69141338/13533028)

Comment: It's Still not working, by removing those codes

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVpFNfnuOZM This video might help.. Actually there is a change in the way flutter implements splashcreen recently.

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash. With your current implementation, there will be a white screen shown before your splash screen loads. Using a native splash avoids this white screen and may solve your release problem, too.  Full disclosure: I maintain this package.