# Can't accept Android Licenses, can't type Y/N after running flutter doctor command (flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, android-licenses

I am learning flutter and installed Android Studio for it. When I run the `flutter doctor` command, I get the message saying that I haven't accepted Android Licenses. But after I run 
`flutter doctor --android-licenses` command, and it tells me that I haven't accepted some licenses and ask me if I want to review them. But I am unable to type Y in the prompt.

**Here to see Image**
[image: Here to see Image]

What should I do to accept the licenses.
I have my Command Line tools to the latest version as well.

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69140837/13997210)

Comment: use a vpn and see if it works.

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I already tried that. I can't type in Y when it asks me to review the licenses

Comment: @Benyamin how would using a vpn make a difference?

Comment: use it, and see the difference.