# Why is the build now under iOS\Build for flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

After upgrading to flutter 2.5 my build is now under the iOS folder and not in the root level as before. Where do i control this or is this a normal behaviour?

I am using Microsoft's Code as an editor.

As this now does happen, i should probably add the folder to .gitignore, correct?

Comment: Try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69140837/13997210) hope its help to you OR delete cache folder inside flutter>bin>cache